# How to validate a UserProfile at the begining of a Controller to show specific data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a UserProfile Model as the following:

```
public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string  Authority { get; set; }
        public string Service { get; set; }
        public string Area { get; set; }
        public int IsWrite { get; set; }

    }
```

the table data looks like the following:

---

UserID  | UseName  |  Position    |     Authority | Service | Area  | IsWrite

---

1      | Peter      |   HSK Manager |   Svc-Ar  | HSK   | WA |  0

2   | Dorothy |     Branch Manager|     Ar  | All   | EA    |1

3   |Mike | HSK Director |  Svc |   HSK |   All |   0

4 | Roddel |    HSK Data Entry |    Svc |   HSK |   All |   1

5 | Susan|  WA Data Entry   |Ar |   All |   WA |    1

6 | Nancy|  Facility COO |  All |   All |   All |   0

7 | Allan | Food Branch Mananger |  Svc-Ar |    FSD |   EA |    0

---

Users has many kinds of authority scope; for example: one has an authority upon a specific service, the other has an authority upon a specific area, and may a user has authority to view records upon a service and an area both. I want to make a logic for each List controller action to check the UserProfile  authority and then list data considering the scope of authority for each user.

this is another model which its data depends on the authority of users called Projects:

```
public class Projects
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }

        public string Service { get; set; }
        public string Area { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Project Name")]
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [DisplayName("Contract Value")]
        public double ContractValue { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName ("Contract Total MP")]
        public int ContractMP { get; set; }

        [Editable(false)]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime )]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime EntryDateTime { get; set; }

    }
```

I want to put a logic in the beginning of the Projects Controller 'Index' action to validate the user's authority; if it's "Svr" it will show only the data of his service, if his authority is "Ar" it will show only data of his Area only, if his Authority is "Svr-Ar" it will show data of his Service and Area only, and if his authority is "All" it will show all data.

I tried many ways to do this, I could not, and I am new to MVC. please help me. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you'd better try to use roles. Then you may simply check:

```
if(Roles.IsUserInRole("Ar"))
{
  //Show data for role Ar
}
```

But you may do the same with your Authority field. Just make simple method:

```
public string GetUserAuthority(int UserID)
{
  var user = db.UserProfile.Find(id);
  return user.Authority;
}
```

or if you use Membership:

```
   public string GetUserAuthority()
    {
      var user = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
      return user.Authority;
    }
```

Then check in Controller Action:

```
if(GetUserAuthority() == "Ar")
{
//Show data for role Ar
}
```